# Address Sanitizer for Process Injection

Tags: android, android-ndk, clang, address-sanitizer, process-injection

has anyone done any process injection address sensitization before? I am trying to get some debug output of any memory leaks and overflows in ASAN from injecting my code into a process, and I was wondering if there is a way to get the output of address offsets for the injected code. Thanks for the help.